# Deleting large quantity of files based on Date Accessed

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I wonder if anyone can advise me.  I have to periodically remove files older than 6 months from various folders on my Windows server and do this manually.  Of course leaving it to delete the files for 'About 35 hours and 20 minutes remaining' is really not suitable, and it appears that the permanent delete option (no going to recycle bin) seems not to work on larger numbers.  Could anyone tell me if there is a better way of doing this hoping to automate it running a dos batch file or the like.  I do need to delete files based on the Date Accessed if that's possible.

Comment: Keep in mind, that the last access timestamp is disabled by default. Anyway, this question is off-topic.

Comment: Thank you, I did find out that and switch it on..  Managed to do something with VB script which at least speeded up the deletion.  Hope the switching on of the date last accessed timestamp won't hinder my performance too much.  Thank you for commenting..